# Limit point of the closed set $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am trying to understand the concept of limit point in general.

For the open set $(0,1)$, earlier discussions on stackexchange showed that all point in the open set $(0,1)$ is a limit point.  Similarly, we can say the same about the closed set $[0,1]$, right ?.  For every point $x$ in the set $[0,1]$, we can find $\epsilon$ neighborhood ($V_{\epsilon}$) such that $V_{\epsilon}(x) \cap A \neq \{\emptyset,x\}$.

If the above comment is true, anyone can give an example of a continuous set containing isolated points ?

Comment: If by "continuous set" you mean an interval, the only possibility is a singleton $\{ a \}$.

Comment: Yes it's true. Continuous set is unfortunately a little bit ambiguous. But if I understood well, indeed, set as $[a,b]$ has no isolated point. But if you take the discrete topology and $x\in [0,1]$, then $[0,1]\cap\{x, -3\}=\{x\}$ and thus $x$ is an isolated point of $[0,1]$

Comment: You need to show that for *every* $\varepsilon$-neighbourhood of $x$, $V_\varepsilon(x) \cap A$ is contains a point in $A \setminus \{x\}$, not that there is one. But indeed all $x\in [0,1]$ are limit points.

Comment: /= {$\emptyset$,x} is a misunderstanding

Comment: @WilliamElliot  I did not get that point. To be a limit point, the intersection should contain a point other than $x$ itself right ?. Otherwise, all isolated points are limit points right ?

Comment: As an intersection of A and an open set will never have the empty set as a member, your statement is always true.  You are misusing set notation.  Not subset of {x} is correct. @Shew

Comment: yes. you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

By "continuous", I think you mean connected.  But a connected set might not have all of its limit points.

Here's an example.  Consider the set $(0,1)$.  It is true that every point in the set is a limit point.  For example, let's look at the point $1/2$.  Is this a limit point?  To be a limit point, we need to create a sequence of points in the set that approach this point.  The Sequence $1/2, 1/2, 1/2, ...$ is such a set of points.

What about the point $0$?  Is $0$ a limit point of this set?  It is!  Consider the sequence $1/2, 1/4, 1/8, 1/16, 1/32, ...$  This sequence is getting closer and closer to the point $0$, and no point in this sequence will ever leave the set $(0,1)$.  Therefore, the set $(0,1)$ does not contain all its limit points.

Any set that contains all of its limit points is called a "closed" set.  So $(0,1)$ is not a compact set.  But $[0,1]$ is.

Comment: A set that contains all it's limit points is closed, but not necessarily compact; for example, $[0,\infty)$ contains all it's limit points but is not compact.

Comment: @User8128  Thank you for correcting my mistake.